# Making href (anchor tag) request POST instead of GET?

Tags: html, post, get, anchor

```
<a href="employee.action" id="employeeLink">Employee1</a>
```

when i click the Employee1 link, GET request goes to server. I want to make it POST instead of GET request.
Is there a way i can change default GET behaviour of href?

Note:- I know it can be done where we can call javascript function on hyperlink click , then create form and submit it. But i am looking where we can mention 
some attribute in anchor tag to make POST request instead of GET request?

Comment: No. You need javascript OR have the get perform a post on the server

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using jQuery it is very simple, assuming the URL you wish to post to is on the same server or has implemented CORS

```
$(function() {
  $("#employeeLink").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the link itself
    $.post(this.href,function(data) {
      $("#someContainer").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

If you insist on using frames which I strongly discourage, have a form and submit it with the link

```
<form action="employee.action" method="post" target="myFrame" id="myForm"></form>
```

and use (in plain JS)

```
 window.addEventListener("load",function() {
   document.getElementById("employeeLink").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // cancel the link
     document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); // but make sure nothing has name or ID="submit"
   });
 });
```

Without a form we need to make one

```
 window.addEventListener("load",function() {
   document.getElementById("employeeLink").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // cancel the actual link
     var myForm = document.createElement("form");
     myForm.action=this.href;// the href of the link
     myForm.target="myFrame";
     myForm.method="POST";
     myForm.submit();
   });
 });
```

Comment: I want to append the post response data data under frame(basically clear old frame html and append new one)
Here is my frame element <frame id="myFrame"  src="myAction" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="myFrame">
</frame>. It tried  $("#myFrame").html(data); but it did not append any data

Comment: Frame? Where do you mention frame? Change the frame to a div - I called it someContainer

Comment: could you see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189365/pass-request-header-authorization-with-anchor-tag

Comment: @mplungjan, this Jquery did not work, it still used GET. I have my <a> tags inside a form already that is having POST but still this happens as GET. Any clue?

Comment: You have to show some code - having a link in a form does not have anything to do with the form

Answer (score 17):

To do **POST** you'll need to have a **form**.

```
<form action="employee.action" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Employee1" />
</form>
```

There are some ways to post data with hyperlinks, but you'll need some javascript, and a form.

Some tricks: [Make a link use POST instead of GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915917/make-a-link-use-post-instead-of-get) and [How do you post data with a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426310/how-do-you-post-data-with-a-link)

Edit: to load response on a frame you can target your form to your frame:

```
<form action="employee.action" method="post" target="myFrame">
```

Comment: You do not need a form to post using javascript

Comment: @mplungjan. As per link provided by you , we can do it with  $.post("WhateverPage.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );  . But what about the HTML response sming from post request? How will i display on html response coming from post request. So looks like i need to create the form and submit