# Why changing my route type from POST to GET to logout worked in Laravel 5.7.12?

Tags: laravel, http

Why changing my route type to:

```php
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

from:

```php
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

works? My link was:

```html
<a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"> logout </a>
```

Just curious.

Comment: Because `<a href` initiates a get request..

Answer (score 1):

To do a `POST` request, you need to have a form or use JS.

`<a href="">` make a `GET` request.

Check this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20906138/7117697).