# How can I get an some entity ID from view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Can I run these get and post actions with just single button? I get an id from my view then I just wanna run my post action.

I've already tried to getting id with parameter and put it in session but couldn't do it with one submit button

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult JoinEvent(int id)
    {
        Session["EventID"] = id;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult JoinEvent(EventPerson eventPerson)
    {
        Person per =(Person) Session["Login"];
        eventPerson.PersonID = per.PersonID;
        eventPerson.EventID = (int)Session["EventID"];
        eventPerson.TotalPerson = eventPerson.TotalPerson + 1;
        eventManager.Join(eventPerson);
        return View();
    }
```

and this is my view

```
<td class="buy_link">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Join","JoinEvent","Join",item.EventID,null)                          
                        </td>
```

Comment: What exactly is the event id coming from ? (Input ? Session value ?)

Comment: I tried to get event id with object route value in the actionlink

Comment: Then bring it to the view and add a hidden input with the value of that route value, the form then will send it to the controller and bind it to `EventPerson` as a property of it, just make sure to add it as a property.

Comment: I edited my post could you look it again? sorry for my english tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what you posted here, it looks like the EventId can be set **freely** (without any security restrictions) by the client by simply navigating to **GET** `/JoinEvent?id=100`.

If security isn't an issue, you can do it by many many ways

Passing the event id to the client, which in turn will give it back to the server.
**How ?** Here is one way

1. Passing it as part of EventPerson model, which you will need to add a new property inside of that model.
   ActionResult should: `return View(new EventPerson { EventId: id })`
2. Decorating view top row (after import statments) with the following `@model EventPerson`, this will tell the view that now he represents this type. (Which was passed by the GET action)
3. Now we should decide if we want to pass it back to the server as query string parameter or a body parameter ? Because we're doing a semantic "Insert" action, in most cases the practice asks us to pass it as part of the body. thus, you should use an hidden text box to pass EventId parameter.

   `@Html.Hidden("EventId", @model.EventId))`

**"EventId"** is the property we want to bind on our POST server action `EventPerson` newly property. (Point#1)

**@model.EventId** is the value we took from the server and passed it into the View (Point#2)

Answer (score 0):

Technically you cannot. When you create an anchor tag using action link, it creates a link to the specified URL. When you click on that link that fires a GET request. That will not POST data to the action method. If you need to POST data, you need to either submit a form or you can use Javascript/jQuery to do that. You can collect the data and send it as a POST using Js/jQuery. But just the anchor won't send a POST method.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906066/making-href-anchor-tag-request-post-instead-of-get)